# Why is it that when the number of loops is increased, the execution is faster than when the number of loops is small?

Tags: php, loops, time, foreach, microtime

Why is this code is faster the executiont time:

```
$start_foreach = microtime(true);
$counter = 1;
foreach (range(1, 1000) as $number) {
    $counter++;
}
$end_foreach = microtime(true);
$time_foreach = ($end_foreach - $start_foreach);
echo "\nExecution time of foreach-loop is $time_foreach second\n";
```

rather than:

```
$start_foreach = microtime(true);
$counter = 1;
foreach (range(1, 10) as $number) {
    $counter++;
}
$end_foreach = microtime(true);
$time_foreach = ($end_foreach - $start_foreach);
echo "\nExecution time of foreach-loop is $time_foreach second\n";
```

just why? I've been looping it many times but still give same result

Please someone explain it to me why is it so?

Comment: Can't reproduce. https://3v4l.org/c5Mo6

Comment: What specific output do you get from running each one?

Comment: @SolomonUcko My lecturer want me to explain di microtime for every loop. What makes me confuse is why is faster when i change the range(1, 10) into range(1, 1000)? even tho when I change it into range(1, 10000) it run more faster. The microtime show smaller number

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're running the test, but my results are different:

[image]

[image]

Run it:

https://onlinephp.io?s=fY5BCoNADEX3gncI4mLECnVti6veQijTMdaBmkicgULp3RuhQt00u5D3fv6pncc5TdIkX4KVcB1Y0LoRzjB5Jxz8hCZIxKJRxHGkgKLHWtcNNWLpjqY-QH0swC6QU5xuKAW80gR0Nq8s1XprDlL__9G6_RBmZ1Sw77oa6EaGrKPLE10MngnWCOABvlD1YJ7Ba7ld9oKOqe8oaz4%2C&v=8.2.1

https://onlinephp.io?s=fY5BCoNADEX3gncI4mLECrq2paveQijTMdaBmkicgULp3RuhQt00u5D3fv7xPI9zmqRJvgQr4TqwoHUjnGDyTjj4CU2QiEWriONIAUWPja4basTSHU1zgKau6wLsAjnF6YZSwCtNQGczy1K9tyYh9f9frdsPYXZGBfu2q4FuZMg6ujzRxeCZYI0AHuALVQ_mGbyW22Uv6Jj6jrL2Aw%2C%2C&v=8.2.1